# Countif Based on Presence of a Date Over Period

Tags: excel, countif

I have 4 columns in question. The period that an issue was logged, then three different issue types with the dates they occurred, N or N/A

```
+--------+----------+----------+----------+
| Period | Stopped  |   Auth   |   Crash  |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+
|    1   | 15/12/18 | 14/12/18 |   N      |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+
|    23  | 19/12/18 |    N/A   |   N      |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+
|    24  | 11/12/18 |    N     | 12/12/18 |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+
```

etc...

In a seperate sheet I have a count for reporting to the business
This needs to give the number of issues by type of the above table

It looks like so

```
+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Period | Stopped  |   Auth   |   Crash  |   Count  |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|    1   | 46       | 45       | 12       | <- =sum  |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|    23  | 12       | 0        | 12       | <- =sum  |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|    24  | 14       | 8        | 1        | <- =sum  |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

etc...

I have the count of all:

```
=COUNTIF('2018'!B:B,D2)
```

But can't work out how to count the individual dates

Rules needed to follow:

Only count dates, ignore "N" and "N/A" (and any other data not a date)

I have tried

```
=COUNTIF('2018'!C:C,"<"&TODAY()*AND('2018'!B:B=D2))
=countif(AND('2018'!B:B=D3,'2018'!C:C=1),'2018'!C:C)
```

The plain text variant should be:

```
Where B=Period(N)
Count number of Format(Date)
```

But this just gives me a count of all the dates in one column

Comment: I understand you have a lot of lines with period 1 period 23 etc. and you want to count the dates appearances in them, right?

Comment: Yes - so re the first table, Period 1 has 26 rows to it and so on down to 52 (next week) Then a count for each stop, crash and auth error that happened in relation to the period (second table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this is what I worked out

Column A - Period - plain text

Column B - Count of Errors - `=COUNTIF('2018'!B:B,D2)`

Column C - Stopped - `=COUNTIFS('2018'!$B:$B,$D2,'2018'!C:C,">43000")`

Column D - Auth - `=COUNTIFS('2018'!$B:$B,$D2,'2018'!D:D,">43000")`

Column E - Crash - `=COUNTIFS('2018'!$B:$B,$D2,'2018'!E:E,">43000")`

`'2018'!$B:$B` refers to The Period of each entry

`">43000"` utlises the fact that date is a glorified number - this is some time in 2016 I believe, way before this report started

`C:C to E:E` refer to the dates entered of Stopped, Auth and Crash

Idea is that the `Countifs` allows to to count in two stages. Part one is to check that the period that's going to be counted second is the same as the period in Column A. Part two makes sure to only count data which is a date - as there will only be dates and text entries possible

[image: Sheet 1]
[image: Sheet 2]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming **Period** column is **A** and Heders row is **1** 
We need to create helper Columns **E** - **Stops is date** and similarly for **F,G**
Now set:

```
E2 = COUNTIF(B2,"??/??/??")
```

And fill all the new rows and columns similarely
This will give 1 whenever original table contains date

Now for the target report we will set **A** as the periods column 
Total stopes at period 1 will be

```
B2 = COUNTIFS('2018'!A:A,A2,'2018'!E:E,1)
```

And fill acordingly the other columns and rows

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Didn't quite hit the mark that I wanted though, but you pushed me in the right direction.